# How does the WinRT Language Projection work for JavaScript in detail?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

Is there any documentation out there that describes in detail how WinRT's language projection works in the JavaScript world in detail?
I know that a WinJS library uses the metadata dynamically and on the fly to create wrapper objects that can be called from JavaScript code that is executed by MS Chakra Engine. However, how does it work in detail in the WinJS library?

Thanks! TH

Comment: You're asking for a fairly elaborate, potentially lengthy answer here.

Comment: I think we might have to wait for windows internals 8.

Comment: WinJS is a helper library written in javascript, similar to jQuery.  It's not technically a part of the language projection.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to really scratch that surface and see how deep the rabbit hole can go, check out Brent Rector's talk at //Build called [Ten Tips When Writing a Hybrid Language Metro style Application](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/PLAT-876T).  Don't let the title fool you, he goes pretty deep into the thought process of WinRT and how it works across the different languages (including a lot on Javascript of course).